# Команда egreep -- color ... Выдаёт ошибку

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Следующая команда выдается ошибку:

```
egreep -- color = auto '<.conf. m\ >' /etc/passwd
```

Мне нужно в каталоге `/etc` найти все слова у которых в конце стоит `conf` и подсветить их.

Comment: `ls /etc/*.conf` если без вложенных каталогов и `find /etc/ -name '*.conf*` если и во всех вложенных фалах.

Comment: Я не смог распарсить что же за команду вы пытались выполнить

Comment: действительно, откройте секрет: что же это за загадочная программа — *egreep*.

Comment: Ну читай ошибку и исправляй то, что там написано.

Comment: Слишком много пробелов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
egrep -I -e 'conf\b' /etc/*  2>/dev/null
```